# I would like to 3 mappings

Tags: solidity, remix, addresses, mapping

I am a beginner.

I would like to 3 mappings

I know 2 mapping looks like this:

```
mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowed;
```

**and my question is: is 3 mappings look like this ?**

```
mapping (address => mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256))) public allowed;
```

anyone can answer my question I will be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be working.

But you can test it out on your own with your specific use-case in [remix](http://remix.ethereum.org/#optimize=false&version=soljson-v0.5.1+commit.c8a2cb62.js&appVersion=0.7.7&evmVersion=null).

Comment: Please mark as answer if it fixed your problem.